# Combine copied data into a single worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently use a VBA script to combine data from multiple sheets and workbooks into a a new workbook. Currently the script does this but creates multiple sheets in the destination workbook. Is it possible to just has destination be a single sheet?

```
Sub copydata()
Dim FolderPath As String, FilePath As String, FileName As String
FolderPath = "C:\attach\"
FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xlsx"
FileName = Dir(FilePath)

 Dim erow As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

 'loops through directory as long as it is not blank and defines files as workbooks.
Do While FileName <> ""
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
'nested loop for sheets in workbooks
For counter = 3 To 9
'Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
wb.Worksheets(counter).Activate
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy

'Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Workbooks("ZMasterFile.xlsx").Worksheets(counter).Activate
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
wb.Close savechanges:=False

 FileName = Dir

Loop

erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1).Select
```

Comment: Where in the script do you create worksheets? Were they not there originally?

Answer (score 0):

This line might causing you the trouble.

```
'Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Workbooks("ZMasterFile.xlsx").Worksheets(counter).Activate
```

On the secound line, you are activating worksheet(counter)

I think you should put Worksheet("Sheet1") if you want all the datas to be in same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  Probably your best bet is to install the AddIn you find from the link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

That tool is very useful!  Try it and you'll see!

Also, see the link below.  You will see all the code exposed there, so it's a great learning example.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm